# dataTables Responsive with Filter

Tags: jquery, filter, responsive-design, datatables

Using the dataTables jQuery plugin, I can add a filter box by initializing it like this:

```
$('#tableID').dataTable({ "sDom": "fRt"});
```

To make the table responsive I initialize it like this:

```
$('#tableID').DataTable({ responsive: true });
```

How can I initialize a dataTable that is responsive and has the filter box?

One uses **d**ataTable() and the other **D**ataTable() and it doesn't seem like you can mix and match parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add your `sDom` to .**D**atatable(). I tried the below and it seems to be working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ebRXw/215/)